# How to achieve strongly typed integers in Python

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses, strong-typing

I don't think that I like that the following is True.  I understand that's the case because `NewType` is only examined by the static checker, and ignored at runtime.  If I want it to be False, what's the best way to do that?  Make a `@dataclass` with a single field like "value", take the performance hit, and write the forwarding functions that you want to have available?

```
from typing import NewType
A = NewType("A", int)
B = NewType("B", int)
print(A(1) == B(1))
```

What I'm doing right now is:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Integer:
   value: int

@dataclass
class A(Integer):
   pass

@dataclass
class B(Integer):
   pass
```

This prevents the classes from being compared, but certainly has a performance hit.  I tried inheriting from int, but that way it does say `A(1) == B(1)` is `True`.

Comment: Python is already strongly typed. Your problem is that `__eq__` is not as *narrowly* typed as you would like it.

Comment: Also (in contrast to Python, where type is synonymous with class), you have to distinguish between types and classes in the DSL that defines type hints. `NewType` creates a new *type*, but does not create a new *class*. At run time, `NewType` simply returns its argument with no change in its class.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `int` and override `__eq__` (and other methods like `__add__`, if appropriate).

```
class A(int):
   def __eq__(self, other):
     return isinstance(other, A) and super().__eq__(other)
 
 class B(int):
   def __eq__(self, other):
     return isinstance(other, B) and super().__eq__(other)
```

```
>>> A(2) == B(2)
False
>>> A(2) == A(2)
True
>>> A(2) == A(3)
False
```

The `__eq__` operator does not inherently need to return `False` if the two objects are different types. If you want that behavior, you'll have to specify that by adding it like above.

Comment: Good practice would be to return `NotImplemented` for `other` of different type.

Comment: That's only good practice if your implementation is otherwise raising errors, but it's not categorically true. NotImplementedError is reasonable when you're not sure how the class you're implementing `__eq__` for would handle the comparison. In this case, the author has made it clear that different types are inherently non-equal, and thus returning False is reasonable and raising an error is incorrect.

Comment: `NotImplemented` is not `NotImplementedError`, it is a built-in constant like Ellipsis for exactly this case. (That's why I said "return", not "raise")

Comment: Ah! You're right. Good point. Hadn't heard of NotImplemented before. Thanks!